# SOAP Service "A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host"

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, vpn

I'm using C# WinForms app to receive data from the remote SOAP service and it's working great on every testing machine with VPN connected/disconnected.

But there is an exception on one PC after connecting it to VPN network:

> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A socket operation was attempted
>   to an unreachable host XX.XX.XX.XX:443

If it's not connected to VPN its receiving data from the service as intended.

What's wrong there? I've tried to disable AVG and firewall but no success.

Is there port blocked after VPN connected or maybe VPN using the same port?... I really don't know what to do :)

netstat doesn't show 433 port in use, btw

I guess this is port issue but who knows...

Comment: your client cannot reach the server when you have the VPN running. Check your routes in the windows routing table for that machine before and after connecting to the VPN, the key lies in the differences you will find. (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779122%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: you mentioned that it works during the tests with or without VPN. can you clarify what is the purpose of the VPN ?  as Maks said, it's probably a routing problem. if you are not Natting through the VPN , make sure to clear "use the default gateway on the network server"

Comment: Adrian, thank you for your comment. But the point is that internet connection is working great and service page is opening fine while I'm connected to VPN. So why the app can't receive info from the service returning this exception? And no issue on other PC. Thx

Comment: @Sam, I'm not sure what are you talking about? Can you clarify your comment please?